# Iterate through value of an object

Tags: c#, list, object, reflection

I have and object say `Object abc = new List<myclass>();`

currently abc is of Type Object and pocess 1000 records say. What my need is to iterate through these values.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `for`, `foreach`, `abc.foreach` etc and *depends* on what you are going to do. What have you tried? Also IMHO, if you know the type then declare that type... for example `List<myclass> abc = new List<myclass>();`...

Comment: Tip: `abc` is not an object, or not *just* an object, it is a collection.

Comment: abc is of Type Object..

Comment: *Why* are you assigning the list to an `object` variable instead of a `List<myclass>` variable?

Comment: Am getting this abc object through reflection. Just for simplicity I put that one statement there.

Comment: @AnishKarunakaran if that's the case then `if (abc is IEnumerable myObj)` should suffice.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Could you details it more with full statement

Comment: @AnishKarunakaran see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) about pattern matching; specifically type pattern. Basically if it can be converted, the `myObj` above will hold that value now, its what you can use to iterate over the items, otherwise the statement is false.

Comment: Got it.. We need to cast the abc as (IEnumerable) when you create the object itself..

Answer (score 1):

Change `abc` to `List<myclass> abc = new List<myclass>();`

then iterate through the records.

```
foreach(var records in abc)
{ 
 //do stuff with records
}
```

Comment: `Object` does not implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: You can't iterate through a Type 'Object'

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, because it is a List.. which implements an indexer method [], you can use a normal for loop as well.. although its less readble (IMO):

for (var i = 0; i < records.Count; i++) {

}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

Also try

for(T item : list) { 
    }

Comment: You can't iterate through a Type 'Object'

Comment: Did the second one work to iterate through type object?

Comment: @JSkyS Considering that the second isn't valid C# at all, no.